# Prop-based dynamic conditional transition class property in Vue - is it even possible?

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2, vue-component

a Vue enthusiast in the making here. Imagine my_face_when:

1. You have a delicious sideNav component that gracefully slides onto screen using `<transition>`.
2. The component is to receive a `right` prop, which gives it a masculine `right-aligned` class.
3. You realize that for it to be a schmacken-backen `right-aligned` it needs to slide from the other side.

Question: How can I ever restore honor of my family not being able to access CSS properties from within the component to somehow swap

```
transform: translate(-100%);
```

with

```
transform: translate(100%);
```

*inside* the `<transition>` required `.slide-enter, .slide-leave-to` CSS class style declaration in the depths of `<style>` tag? I think I'm dying, please avenge me.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me one day and few cigarette to figure this out, **but** since I cannot mingle with `<style>` folks, I went on and established a binding:

```
<transition :name="slideSide">
```

, a rather compact urban `computed` method:

```
computed: {
  slideSide() {
    if (this.right) {
      return "slideRight";
    }
    return "slideLeft";
  }
},
```

and, finally, two completely separate sets of CSS transition classes:

```
.slideLeft-enter, .slideLeft-leave-to {
  transform: translate(-100%);
  ...

.slideRight-enter, .slideRight-leave-to {
  transform: translate(100%);
  ...
```

It works as expected, my family honor is restored. As this solution utterly destroys DRY paradigm, I will be waiting here in case any of YOU has a better solution, gonna mark it as the answer. Tschüss!